# Import volumetric video (OBJ sequences)

Tags: python, animation, obj

I have a set of OBJ files (1000+) with the associated texture maps as JPG files. I want to import those into Blender using the Python API either sequentially or all at once and play them while changing the camera location and rendering views from different camera positions. Is this possible using Python?

Comment: It's possible. My suggestion is for you to sequentially break down your workflow and look for things in order. (eg) 1. import obj file 2. import multiple files 3. Change camera locations 4. Render. All these keywords have multiple answers associated on this website alone. Cheers

Comment: Have you tried this Blender plugin? https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ It does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @rafapages Thanks, that looks like a very promising tool. I will give it a try.